# PhpStorm method not found in class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm, laravel-5.5

I'm working on a project using Laravel 5.5 and I'm using PhpStorm as IDE but it shows me

> "Method 'table' not found in \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB..."
>   "Referenced method is not found in subject class.. "

The code however is working perfectly but still want to know the perfect syntax.

Comment: [an IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) might be helpful

Comment: Also : https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/15 is literally for this topic

Comment: There is the same error even using the IDE helper

Answer (score 9):

even if you install the barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper the problem persist, there's a quick solution for this problem, if you look in the /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php class and Add this PhpDoc

```
/**
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 * @mixin \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
```

PhpStorm will now recognize all the Query building methods for all your models

Comment: in laravel .5.5.40 and barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ^2.4 not work this.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. While its not clean to edit composer installed files, and it WILL revert with the next release, it does work! Thanks @Alejandro!

Comment: It looks like you can also just add

`/**
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 */`
To each of your Model PhpDoc's with the same effect. That's the route I am taking.

Answer (score 4):

Install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
```

register it in `config/app.php`

use it to generate facades doc

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

Comment: Don't stop at generate for PHPStorm, use ide-helper:meta as well.

Comment: In addition, there's a Laravel plugin which should be installed as well. Best way would be to follow https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm guide.

Comment: I was having this issue, and I've looked all over and tried many different things.

This answer, coupled with with `php artisan ide-helper:models --write` finally got rid of the false errors.

Just the composer command and two artisans did it for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is already mentionned here : 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9162

It is an issue after 5.0.33 update.

Try directly this in your code:

```
\DB::table('...')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable helpers for ide it is important to add "User::query()" if we user query() method then ide will not give such warnings it is best way to easily find eloquent feature.

Without ::query() we can't analyse that followed functions like "where, with, all, get" recognized or not.